# how to solve:Revolution Slider Error: The param Slider Width should not be empty?

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

In my word-press website suddenly Revolution Slider is not working its giving error:
Revolution Slider Error: The param Slider Width should not be empty.
how to solve this problm?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have set all settings according to our manual https://www.sliderrevolution.com/manual/standard-background-spacing-and-border-styling-options/ and then save the module again. Maybe a network hiccup during the update process has eaten up a default setting?

If it still is a problem please do not hesitate to contact our support team at https://support.sliderrevolution.com, thanks.